# Deeplinking URLs don't show up in Branch.io Dashboard

Tags: json, git, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using branch.io for my android app. I am trying to generate via POST method and this is the code:

```
 {"branch_key":"key_test_lerbZ22zyjfpfFtl2auzukafywi220dN", "campaign":"new_product_annoucement", "channel":"email", "tags":["monday", "test123"], 
"data":"{\"name\": \"Alex\", \"email\": \"alex@branch.io\", \"user_id\": \"12346\", \"$desktop_url\": \"https://file.town/download/odrqliwc94d440jt08wxngceo\",\"$marketing_title\": \"2\"}"}
```

In the dashboard, the campaign can be seen, the channel can be seen, and the generated URL goes to the desired site. But the generated URL does not show up in the Marketing tab in the dashboard to show the URL's statistics with regards to clicks, downloads and installs.

Is there any code I am missing in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the Branch HTTP API to create a link that shows up in the Marketing section of the Branch dashboard you need to add the parameter "type":2 at the root level of the request. You will also want to use a $marketing_title that is descriptive.

Here is an updated curl request using the parameters you provided:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"type":2, "branch_key":"key_test_lerbZ22zyjfpfFtl2auzukafywi220dN", "campaign":"new_product_annoucement", "channel":"email", "tags":["monday", "test123"], "data":"{\"name\": \"Alex\", \"email\": \"alex@branch.io\", \"user_id\": \"12346\", \"$desktop_url\": \"https://file.town/download/odrqliwc94d440jt08wxngceo\",\"$marketing_title\": \"Super Amazing Branch Link\"}"}' https://api.branch.io/v1/url
```

Comment: Getting this error:{"error":{"code":403,"message":"You don't have access to this type. Please try again with type 0 (default) or 1."}}